# How to have optional keys in TypedDict?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typeddict

I am trying to create a `TypedDict` with optional keys but neither `Optional` neither `NotRequired` does not work. (I tried `NotRequired` based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70904437/1157814))

```
class MyTypedDict(TypedDict):
    my_key1: Optional[int]
    my_key2: NotRequired[int]

my_variable = MyTypedDict()
```

For both keys I got `Parameter 'my_key1' unfilled` and `Parameter 'my_key2' unfilled`

What am I missing?

Comment: Which typechecker do you use?

Answer (score 15):

[`NotRequired`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NotRequired) is exactly what you are looking for. `Optional[int]` means `int | None`, but the item is still required. Any item that is annotated as `NotRequired[int]` can be ommitted as stated in [PEP 655](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/).

**Note:** If you import `Required` or `NotRequired` from `typing_extensions` (on Python <3.11), you should also import `TypedDict` from `typing_extensions`.

So if your type-checker supports this feature, it should only complain about missing `my_key1`.

```py
# Python >= 3.11
from typing import Optional, NotRequired, TypedDict

# Python < 3.11
from typing import Optional
from typing_extensions import NotRequired, TypedDict


class MyTypedDict(TypedDict):
    my_key1: Optional[int]
    my_key2: NotRequired[int]

my_variable = MyTypedDict()
# mypy error: Missing key "my_key1" for TypedDict "MyTypedDict"
# pyright error: Argument missing for parameter "my_key1"
```

Comment: Many thx. Unfortunately it seems PyCharm build in type checker does not supports this, I got 'Value must be a type' for the `NotRequired[int]` line. I do not know which type checker PyCharm is using, but it seems it is not trivial to get which is it, neither configure external type checker to work seamlessly with IDE

Answer (score 3):

You can mix required and optional values with inheritance and `total`. From the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#mixing-required-and-non-required-items)

```
class MovieBase(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int

class Movie(MovieBase, total=False):
    based_on: str
```

> `Movie` has required keys `name` and `year`, while `based_on` can be left out when constructing an object